# "Scrambled" webkit scrollbar (trying to reproduce Google+'s scrollbar)

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, pseudo-class

I'm trying to reproduce google+'s scrollbar on my site. For reasons I can't figure out sometimes this scrollbar has a scrambled appearance. By scrambled, I mean the scrollbar is multi-colored, has a black line spanning it, and the `scrollbar-thumb` is not visible. Here's a screenshot to show you what i mean:

[image]

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XkGuu/31/) where unfortunately, the scrollbar looks normal so I haven't been able to reproduce my problem.

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) if that is helpful for thinking about how my existing CSS could be screwing this up.

Comment: I thinks its a bug in webkit. I've seen similar things with many css3 functions. (especially `box-shadow`)

Comment: @Teak, then why does google+ website and my jafiddle look fine on my same browser? must be some kind of rule collision?

Comment: Possible, but it's still a bug. You should never see whats in the screenshot. I only ever have the problem intermittently.

Comment: yes it's intermittent, but this still means scrollbar is unusable at this point, I don't have problems with box-shadow, again very weird/annoying

Comment: When I was having problems it was when I was changing `box-shadow` on mouse hover. This leads me to believe it has something to do with the way Webkit handles css3 animation, or maybe any css3 that changes after load. Unfortunately I never solved my problem, and gave up after a few hours of battling with it.

Comment: @Teak thanks, i guess we'll just have to see over time how these issues resolve themselves.

Comment: @meagar: You broke the image link :P

Answer (score 0):

This the code used for the scroll bar See the code below:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
height: 16px;
overflow: visible;
width: 16px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
background-clip: padding-box;
border: solid transparent;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 6px;
min-height: 28px;
padding: 100px 0 0;
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07);
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
height: 0;
width: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-clip: padding-box;
border: solid transparent;
border-width: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```